# Hide Objects Outside Viewpoint

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there anyway you can 'hide' all the DisplayObjects around the crosshairs on a movie clip?

For example:

[image: example]

If I dragged a that movie clip onto the stage, how could I have only B show? and have A hidden?

EDIT: Basically, the image shows two rectangles in a MC named "First". If I were to drag this movie clip onto the scene, I only want rectangle B to be shown. When the mouse is hovered over B, an event listener is triggered which slides rectangle A down to 'overlay' B. I don't want A to be shown otherwise.

Thanks.

Comment: Your image is broken - can you update?

Comment: Here's the image: http://postimage.org/image/4d3lfz2fn/ However, I find the question impossible to understand.

Comment: Please give some more details so any body can understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a mask is what you need:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#mask

http://www.the-flying-animator.com/flash-mask.html

Answer (score 1):

Ok... assuming I understood the question, which I'm not sure... you want to hide all the DisplayObjects given `x + width < 0` and `y + height < 0` within a MovieClip.

A simple loop in the children list should do that:

```
for (var childIdx:int in numChildren) {
    var child:DisplayObject = getChildAt(childIdx);
    if (child.x + child.width < 0 || child.y + child.height < 0) {
        child.visible = false;
    }
}
```